# How should this Google URL be interpreted?

Tags: url, gmail

https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin

In the above URL, what does the following terms mean?

1. passive = true
2. rm = false
3. ss = 1
4. scc
5. ltmpl = default
6. ltmplcache = 2
7. emr = 1
8. osid = 1
9. flowName = GlifWebSignIn

For example in the link here, 
https://www.google.com/search?q=Tree&hl=en

q means query
hl = en tells that the results should be returned in ('host language' (I guess)) English.

In this way, what does the above URL mean?

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to https://developers.google.com/identity for that.
While the https://www.google.com/search URL points to the Google search engine, the https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier URL represents the Google identity service.
Maybe the best way to interact with it is using a library/module for the language/platform you want to use. This way you have no need to bother with the various parameters after the "?" in the URL. Maybe OAuth 2.0 would be a good start point.

Comment: Thanks @daghemo I will check it out.